# Has_many accepts_nested_attributes Can't mass assign attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm having issues with a form in a custom registration for Devise. This form needs to have both User and Business model information in there that I'll be creating both at once on the form. It's important that this can't be a multi-step registration form - I need to have both the User and Business models filled out simultaneously, as part of the requirements.

I have the following models:

```
user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :businessusers, :include => :business
  has_many :businesses, :through => :businessusers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :businessusers
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name, :role, :businessusers

business.rb
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :businessusers
  has_many :users, :through => :businessusers

businessuser.rb
class Businessuser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
  belongs_to :user
end

businessusers migration
create_table :businessusers do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :business_id
end
```

In my registration form, I have the following code:

```
Business Information
<br>
<%= f.fields_for :businessusers do |business_form| %>
<%= business_form.input :name %>
<%= business_form.input :address_line1 %>
<%= business_form.input :address_line2 %>
<%= business_form.input :city %>
```

Finally, here is my controller:
`custom_registration_controller.rb`

```
def create
@user=User.new(params[:user])
@business = @user.businesses.build(params[:business]) unless params[:business]  [:name].blank?
end
```

EDIT: I've gotten past the mass assign attribute problem, but now I have another one.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? Before, I was disabling id on businessusers table. But this gave me an error saying I needed a primary ID on the table. So when I allow the field `:id`, it makes it so that the form no longer has the business fields on it.

Thanks!